# Find contour of difference between images

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, imagick

I am trying to find the contours of one or several differences between two images.

Suppose you have two identical images. Then add an opaque square and triangle to one of the images at random locations. The shapes may not overlap.

I want to get the coordinates of the outermost pixels of these shapes and these coords must be 'grouped' -> I want to get two sets of coordinates, one set for each shape.

I have tried comparing each pixel and taking the minimum and maximum x and y values which gives me the bounding box of a shape. Which has two problems: it gives me the bounding box, not the contours of the shape. And it only works if you have no more than one shape in an image.

I can't for the life of me think of a way to get this done.

I am pretty much tied to php, but can go with either gd or imagick. I have a slight preference towards gd, but imagick is faster and more powerful, so that's ok too.

Bonus points: the end result should be a simple (as simple as possible) polygon per shape. Some loss of precision is ok, and is in fact encouraged. The lines of the polygon don't have to follow the contours perfectly, some deviation is allowed in favor of fewer points.

**Edit:**
What I mean by 'contour' is this: Suppose I have an image with a rectangle painted on it. The contour I would like to find are the four points that make up the rectangle. The image this square is painted on can be any image. It might be a white canvas or a landscape or a portrait, you name it.
And what I am realising now is that the order of the points are important. I have to be able to re-draw the square and not end up with an hourglass shape.

**Edit 2:**
I am a step closer using imagick.

```
convert img/modified.png img/original.png -compose ChangeMask -composite out.png
```

This command uses the original as a mask to the modified version and gives me an image with only the shape in it. Maybe with this image I can use a standard edge detection algorithm.
One persisting problem: it only works if there is only one shape in the image. But if that turns out to be a consequence than I guess it would be ok.

**Edit 3:**
I am now able to get the contours of not too complex shapes. But it results in hundreds of points, which is way too much. It should be compressed down to about maybe 20 points.

The process is as follows:

- I use the above imagemagick command which gives me an image with just the shape, the rest of the image is transparant
- In this image I start at the top (0,0) and look down to find a non transparent pixel. Then I look at (1,0) etc. When I reach  the end I start at (width,0) and look left for a non transparent pixel. This way I go all around the image to 'feel' the contours.

Comment: Why don't you try one of standard contour algorithms? For example, canny, gradient, laplasian…

Comment: Those algorithms are for edge detection, which is not what I am trying to do. You could view it as finding the differences between two images.

Comment: Then tell what do you mean by "contour"? If this is an isoline, you can use marching squares algorithm.

Comment: @Eddy_Em see edited question. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an image of what you're trying to achieve?  Something more complex than just the rectangle example.  The 2 source images, and your desired outcome.  That'd help to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/square.html) is a decent walkthrough of several contour tracing algorithms.  Personally, I have used the [Moore-neighborhood tracing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html) algorithm ([another link](http://www.thebigblob.com/moore-neighbor-contour-tracing-algorithm-in-c/#more-21)) with good results.  I find that to be accurate and it preserves the order so you don't wind up with the hourglass problem.

However before I get to that point I often will have to do some preprocessing ([morphological filters](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm) or image subtraction (as you found out)).

After these two steps you should have a collection of points.   You have two options:

1) Complex: collect them into vectors.  If vectors dramatically change slope (or direction) you know you have a point.  Command line tools like [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)  can do this.  The algorithm for potrace is [here](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/potrace.pdf) and is very good.  In your simple rectangle example this will work, but it will also work in a more complex scenario like a circle (you will just have lots of vectors for a circle).

2) Simple: travel the pixels you have found using Moore-Neigborhood and determine change of direction.  (aka if three pixels make a line and the next three are not "inline" by some threshold x, then you have a corner).  This algorithm will work for the square but start to fall apart for more complex images like octogons and circles where the angle delta's between lines are more obtuse.

If all of your shapes are simple enough (square circle ect.) you may also consider template matching (simple shape detection).  A good link is located [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/) in the Aforge documentation.